# STM8 Pulse Counter

Tags: c, encoder, stm8

I am developing a control for a DC motor. This motor has an encoder that generates pulses according to its movement.

I need to control the number of turns of the motor shaft by monitoring the number of pulses.

I am using SMT8S103F3 for this application.

The idea is to use Timer1 as a pulse counter. For this, I configured the Timer to receive an external signal, in this case the encoder pulses, and with each pulse the counter must be increased.

I followed the document ST RM0016 chapter 17.4.3. However the application is not working. The counter is not incrementing.

Follows the developed code.

```
void config_counter(){
  TIM1_PSCRH = 0;
  TIM1_PSCRL = 0; //Prescalar 1 division
  TIM1_ARRH = 0;
  TIM1_ARRL = 0;  //Auto counter disabled
  TIM1_CNTRH = 0;
  TIM1_CNTRL = 0; //Reset counter
  TIM1_IER = 0; //Interrupt disabled
  TIM1_SR1 = 0; //Clear Interrupt
  TIM1_CCMR2 |= 1<<0; //External pulse source T1C2
  TIM1_CCER1 |= ~(1<<5); //Rising edge
  TIM1_SMCR |= 3; //T1C2 input
  TIM1_CR1 |= ~(1<<0); //Counter disabled
  
  return;
}

void set_counter_enable(uint8_t enable){
  if(enable==1)
    TIM1_CR1 |= 1<<0;
  else
    TIM1_CR1 |= ~(1<<0);

  return;
}

void set_counter_updown(uint8_t updown){
  if(updown==1)
    TIM1_CR1 |= ~(1<<4);
  else
    TIM1_CR1 |= 1<<4;

  return;
}

uint8_t start_movement_monitor(uint8_t dir){

  while(1){
    if(dir == 1){
      if(((TIM1_CNTRH<<8)+TIM1_CNTRL)>200)
        return 1;
    }else if(dir == 2){
      if(((TIM1_CNTRH<<8)+TIM1_CNTRL)<50)
        return 1;
    }
    else{
      return 1;
    }
  }

  return 1;
}


int main() {

  config_gpio();
  config_counter();
  set_counter_updown(0);
  set_counter_enable(0);

  set_counter_enable(1);
  set_motor_enable(1);
  set_motor_movement(1);

  start_movement_monitor(1);

  set_motor_movement(0);
  set_motor_enable(0);
  set_counter_enable(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

If the Timer is not the best option for this application, how could the pulse counter be implemented?

The pulse frequency is 700kHz.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the STM8s, having barely pulled my first STM silicon from the bag (an stm32). I'm noting that 700khz on a 16mhz device comes out to about 1 operation per 22 clocks and can't help but wonder if an on-change interrupt wouldn't be better.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

To use the timer on a stm8 pin it is necessary to write the option bytes to change the pin's function.
This is accomplished by writing the AFR0.

The timer configuration to use timer 1 channel 2 was as follows.

```
void config_counter(){
  TIM1_CNTRH = 0;
  TIM1_CNTRL = 0; //Reset counter
  TIM1_IER = 0; //Interrupt disabled
  TIM1_SR1 = 0; //Clear Interrupt
  TIM1_CCMR2 |= 1<<0; //External pulse source T1C2
  TIM1_CCER1 &= ~(1<<5); //Rising edge
  TIM1_SMCR |= (7<<0); //External Clock Source
  TIM1_SMCR |= (6<<4); //T1C2 Input Source
  TIM1_CR1 &= ~(1<<0); //Counter disabled
  
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TIM1_CR1 |= ~(1<<0); //Counter disabled` does not disable the counter. It leaves `CEN` unchanged, and sets all other bits to `1` - including `OPM`. You want `&=` instead. Same for `set_counter_updown`.

Comment: You're right. But it still didn't work. There is another error in the timer configuration.

Comment: TIM1_SMCR |= (7<<0); //External Clock Source
TIM1_SMCR |= (6<<4); //T1C2 Input Source

Comment: There was a configuration error in TIM1_SMCR. But the change did not work.

Comment: Should I write the option byte AFR0 to enable the Input Timer?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions to this problem.

The solution with the timer requires that the clock input for the timer be associated to the motor pulse, and this requires some external hardware connections that I don't know if you have available.  The benefits are that you can just read the timer value to know the number of turns and that using the prescaler you can scale your input.  The drawbacks are that the number of timers is normally limited (you have one or two timers only) and also that the timer is always configured to count motor turns, and you cannot use it for other thing.

The other solution is to associate an interrupt line for the motor pulse and to program an interrupt handler.  You need to associate (by hardware) an interrupt to the motor pulses, so when you receive the interrupt the interrupt handler *increments a variable*.

Once you have this.... you just have to check what is the variable value, as the update of the variable just reflects how many times the motor has turn.

```
volatile long loops = 0;

void motor_pulse_handler()
{
    loops++;
}

int main()
{
    /* this function installs the handler to be called each time the motor starts a new turn. */
    install_handler(MOTOR_PULSE_INTERRUPT, motor_pulse_handler);
    ...
    for (;;) {
        printf("\rloops: %ld", loops);
        usleep(10000);
    }
}
```

The function `install_handler` is a function that strongly depends on the hardware.  It is normally provided as a library function by the development system, because it requires to know a bit of the processor architecture to implement.  You first need to disable interrupts completely while you are manipulating the interrupt related controls.  Then it must activate for the cpu to be interrupted on a pulse in the corresponding interrupt line (this is the reason to include a `MOTOR_PULSE_INTERRUPT` in the parameter list, this should be `#define`d with a proper value to make the motor pulse the selected signal, and not other signal)  Finally it mus reenable interrupts again.  When an interrupt comes in, then your function will be called in the middle of the sequence of things the processor can be doing.

Normally, installing an interrupt handler is a two phase process.  The routine actually called is not the one you pass to the `install_handler`  but a different routine that does some hardware stuff.  The interrupt handler is called with interrupts inhibited, it should:

- save all the cpu state (registers, flags, etc) so the state can be restored at the end.
- mask interrupts of this device, so it will not interrupt again (the interrupt has not been acknowledged to the device, so if you enable interrupts, the cpu will be interrupted again)
- enable interrupts so other higher priority interrupts can interrupt the cpu from this point on.
- call the user interrupt handler, so the counter can be updated.
- disable interrupts again.
- acknowledge the interrupt.  This normally means to read some chip register to indicate to the interrupt hardware this interrupt was acknowledged.  This resets the device so it doesn't interrupt again for the same reason, when you return from the interrupt.
- restore registers and flags (all cpu state) so we can return to the point on which the cpu was interrupted.
- do a RETURN FROM INTERRUPT.  This is normally a special return instruction (not the one used to return from an normal function call)

The advantages of this solution is that you can deinstall the signal handler and this will stop the counting process.  Again, reusing the interrupt line for other things is only possible if you implement some mechanism to route the interrupts (this problem is similar to the one in the timer, in which the pulses come to the input of the timer selected)

Comment: I used the interrupt to count the pulses, but it had not worked well. The count was returning wrong. I suspected it was due to the speed of the pulses. For this reason I was trying to use the timer.